# Doing a "sudo sed -i 's/bullseye/bookworm/g' /etc/apt/sources.list" to go from Debian 11 to 12, shall I deal with "source.list.d" in the same move?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I am planning to upgrade from Debian 11 to Debian 12 soon.

The main action I intend to take is:

`sudo sed -i 's/bullseye/bookworm/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

The `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory contains additional `.list` source files.

Do you recommend using `sed` on the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` files as well before executing the `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade commands`?

Should I simply modify the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and then perform a reboot?

Wouldn't this result in a mixed system, with some parts running Debian 11 and others running Debian 12?

Comment: I upgraded a dozen bullseye to bookworm recently - I edited all appropriate apt config files by hand (not just the `.list` files by the way, but that's my setup) - it takes a couple minutes with the number of repos I have in `sources.list.d` - but it's SAFE. As for modifying sources.list and rebooting, that does NOT result in a mixed system, since you haven't even updated let alone upgraded anything

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! What are the config files that you have to edit too, but that aren't `.list`? For two major upgrades, I haven't edited something else than `.list`.

Comment: I have some files in preferences.d to pin some packages - since they refered to bullseye, all I did was update them to also refer to bookworm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the [Debian 12 release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/releasenotes), [you should update all your repository configuration](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrade-process) ([also available in French](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.fr.html#upgrade-process)).

Your `sed` command might not be sufficient: Debian 12 has [a new section for non-free firmware](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#non-free-split), if your system relies on that you’ll need to adjust your configuration accordingly.

As a general rule, please follow the release notes for the upgrade you’re trying to undertake.